# Possible side effects using map() index as key property in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) there is a reference to [this article](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) where author writes (quote refers to array of JSX elements where map.`index` is used as `key`)

> Let me explain, a key is the only thing React uses to identify DOM
>   elements. What happens if you push an item to the list or remove
>   something in the middle? If the key is same as before React assumes
>   that the DOM element represents the same component as before. But that
>   is no longer true.

I don't fully understand this, so want to ask

**What as possible side effects using `map()` `index` as `key` property in React?**

Comment: key is to uniquely identify element. If your data is structured in such a way that index can be used to uniquely individual element, they you may use index as key

Comment: @alt255 I know purpose of `key`, but wonder about some use cases that using `index` may result in unexpected behaviour like in this article : https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: Please check this two example from official docs  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMaXrr?&editors=0010 and https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQBOML?&editors=0010